# PHP - Нужно отправить запрос в базу данных из массива

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, у меня есть какой-то, заданный мной, массив `$myarray = array('Керосины', 'Абрикосы', 'Соли', 'Паспорта');`, а также у меня есть запрос к базе данных, найти там эти слова из массива:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemsname LIKE :iname');
 $stmt->execute(Array('iname' => '%'.$iname.'%'));
```

где переменная `$iname` - это моя попытка сделать правильный запрос `$iname = implode(',',$myarray);`, в итоге естественно он просто ищет все 4 слова вместе, через запятую. Теперь вопрос - А как сделать так, чтобы он искал по очереди каждое слово массива? И заносил в какое-нибудь поле через цикл, при совпадении? Тоесть в итоге нужно сделать, чтобы я, нажимая на желтую кнопку получал результат в зеленом блоке ниже (функционал умею писать, просто прошу с запросом и выводом помочь).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Update (Решение моей проблемы, спасибо за наводку в ответах):

```
$myarray = array('Керосины', 'Абрикосы', 'Соли', 'Паспорта');   
$implod = implode('|',$weaparray);
$total = count($myarray);
foreach ($myarray as $key => $keyword) {
echo '<a href="?type='.$keyword.'" class="iname">'.$keyword.'</a>';
}
if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemsname LIKE :iname');   
$stmt->execute(Array('iname' => $_GET['type'].'%'));
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 }
}
```

Comment: вам скорее всего придется в начале в цикле сформировать строку запроса с некоторым количеством LIKE, а потом впихнуть массив данных... то есть строка у вас в итоге должна будет получится типа `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE ? OR column1 LIKE ? OR column2 LIKE ?`  а данные потом вставить `$query->execute(array("%$value1%","%$value2%",.....));` ... как один из вариантов

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, спасибо за вариант, но собственно я привел лишь пример, а в действительности у меня массив из 30 элементов, а не 4. Тоесть это как минимум 30 OR, ? и в сам массив к каждому элементу %%, так бы я мог пойти путем костылей и сделать просто 4 кнопки, чтобы при нажатии посылался, например, запрос GET и отображал все LIKE, но в этот раз это не выход(

Comment: ну а какая вам разница 4 или 30, если строку запроса формировать в цикле, а не вручную? Да и это все же не запрос в цикле........может тогда попробовать `REGEXP`? `SELECT * FROM items WHERE 1 = (SELECT itemsname REGEXP "val1|val2|val3");`

Comment: даже еще проще `SELECT * FROM items WHERE  itemsname REGEXP "val1|val2|val3";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в вашем случае сделать запрос не через `LIKE`, а через **[REGEXP](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Regexp.html)**.

В общем случае запрос будет:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `items` 
WHERE `itemsname` REGEXP "val1|val2|val3";
```

то есть нужно будет массив разбить не по знаку `,`, а по прямой черте `|`

то есть `$iname = implode('|',$myarray);`

Так  как запрос

```
WHERE `col` LIKE '%val1%' OR `col` LIKE '%val2%' ...
```

в принципе равнозначен такому

```
WHERE `col` REGEXP 'val1|val2|...'
```

---

Либо формировать строку запроса и вставляемый данные через цикл. Что-то типа такого:

```
$keywords = array('Керосины', 'Абрикосы', 'Соли', 'Паспорта');
$totalKeywords = count($keywords);
$query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemsname LIKE ?";

for($i = 1 ; $i < $totalKeywords; ++$i){
  $query .= " OR itemsname LIKE ? ";
}

$sql = $this->db->prepare($query);

foreach ($keywords as $key => $keyword) {
  $sql->bindParam($key + 1, '%'.$keyword.'%');
}
$sql->execute();
```

Comment: Тоесть, чтобы я мог контролировать, какое из слов массива собственно использовать, то лучше использовать 2 вариант? Т.к. первый применяет OR и у меня подряд 3800 строк, там где есть значения из массива, а мне надо еще как-то циклом сделать, чтобы создавались 4 <a></a> элемента, где написано в каждом по слову из массива и при нажатии на каждое, открывались собственно результаты именно их, а не всех стразу

Comment: А вот, огромное спасибо, я попробовал, а потом вы напомнили про foreach и как его использовать, дело сдвинулось с мертвой точки, в ответ к своему вопросу добавлю, что я хотел получить